# How to override the external CSS using some condition in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually, I have an application for different countries in different languages and external CSS is defined for all the HTML elements on the Page using classes and Id's. What I want is to change the font of the whole website for a particular country but I don't want to do it by applying the CSS to all the classes again and again. So Is there a way that I can change the CSS(font) of whole website in a go or by using a convenient way.

Comment: Yes you need to define the css font-family in body for entire page, and just need to override this.

Comment: Yeah..I Have already tried that method but its not working. Thnx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact that you're saying there's styles set by ID, the only way to really override these without doing specific style for each element, would be inline styles.

To avoid having to set it for every class like in the example above, you would do something like this instead:

`$('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a').css('font-family', 'verdana');`

In the selector part (the first part) you either go through [this list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/) and take all relevant elements - or better yet: go through a few samples of the pages you're going to be using and select the relevant html elements from there. It shouldn't really take that long.

For the part about making your solution work on only specific languages/countries I would do something like this:

`$('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a', 'body.en-us, body.en-ca').css('font-family', 'verdana');`

Then you can apply class 'en-us', 'en-ca', 'fr-fr' to the body tag and use this to target your javascript changes for those specific countries. Depending on what kind of changes you need to do or how many countries you need to do this for, another approach could be to apply a 'font-verdana' class or something similar to the body tag for those countries and then simply use this as the parent selector instead of the countries/locales.

Comment: Hey thanx a lot for your help..I have tried $(" * ") and it is selecting all the elements but now I am stuck in getting the elements that are being created dynamically by javascript because by using the above approach, it is only selecting the elements that exists in the DOM.

Comment: The $("*") approach might be a bit overkill as it actually selects everything including script tags and whatnot. I can't guarantee that it won't break something when you start applying unsupported attributes to those html tags.
In regards to catching elements added to the DOM dynamically, I think the only solution is to continuously apply the css with a timer. As far as I know, events triggering when elements are added to the DOM unfortunately has been deprecated and no longer trigger.
You might be able to find a plugin that does this though so you won't have to reapply to all elements again.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to add Class to all of elements again and again. Adding class to body is enough to solve your problem. Please take a look at following code.

```
     if(/* Check your users's country, suppose that your users are in China */){
            $("body").addClass("font-chinese");
        } else if(/* So on */) {
            // keep on adding body class
      }
```

and your CSS file

```
body {
    font-family: default-font;
}
body.font-chinese .container-element {
    font-family: chinese-font;
}
body.font-another-country .container-element {
    font-family: another-font;
}
```

Your child elements in `.container-element` will use inherited CSS properties from `.container-element`, so you just change `font-family` of `.container-element`, it will effect all child elements with out having to add class to all of those ones individually again and again.

Comment: And be sure to use __SASS__ or __LESS__ for that kind of staff, it's pretty easy to make many themes

Comment: @evc Thanks for your useful comment :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your concern.. I will surely try that way.. :)

Comment: @evc Thanks for ur concern but we can't use that in our project :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
$('.mysentence').css('font-face', "Arial,sans-serif");
```

Comment: Yeah this method works but I have to do it for all the classes on the page So it's too time consuming and also can't do it.

Comment: You need to add a common class name where you can do this consistently in a one-time deal. That's a long-term solution I can think of. That or use the body selector with the same code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have used the $('*') for applying CSS to all the elements and for the elements that are being created dynamically, we can use "DOMNodeInserted" event and deal with the dynamically created elements.